# How do I show data from MySQL using PHP and Javascript into leaflet popup on the marker?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, leaflet

Ok, this is my first time asking a question here. Please don't bully me.

This has been asked before and I tried to solve it myself, yet it just won't work.

Here is my problem: As stated in the question, I can't seem to call the data from MySQL into the marker's popup.

I tried to use `<code>json_encode</code>` to print it in the Javascript popup.The result is either `show [object] [object]` in the popup, or the leaflet map won't load at all. 
If I remove the `<code>marker.bindPopup()</code>`, the code works fine.

Here is the code :

```
<div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 500px;"></div>

              <?php
                  $result = mysqli_query($konek,"SELECT dep,mag FROM data_gempa_jawa");
                  $rows = array();
                  while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                      $rows[] = $r;
                  }
              ?>

              <!-- This is for the leaflet maps -->
              <script type="text/javascript">

                <?php include "planelatlong.php"; ?>

                var tiles = L.tileLayer('//{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                  maxZoom: 18,
                  attribution: '&copy; <a href="//openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Points &copy 2012 LINZ'
                });

                var map = L.map('map', {
                  center: L.latLng(-6.6, 106.42),
                  zoom: 5,
                  layers: [tiles]
                });

                var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup({
                  chunkedLoading: true,
                  //singleMarkerMode: true,
                  spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true
                });

                for (var i = 0; i < planelatlong.length; i++) {
                  marker = new L.marker([planelatlong[i][1],planelatlong[i][2]]);
                  marker.bindPopup("<?php print json_encode($rows); ?>");
                  mcg.addLayer(marker);
                  marker.on('click', onClick);
                }
                  function onClick(e) {
                    var popup = e.target.getPopup();
                    var content = popup.getContent();
                  }
                map.addLayer(mcg);

              </script>
```

Here is the "planelatlon.php" code :

```
<?php
    include "koneksi.php";
    $select = mysqli_query($konek,"SELECT id,lat,lon FROM data_gempa_jawa");

    if ( ! $select ) {
        echo mysqli_error();
        die;
    }

    $data = array();

    echo "var planelatlong = [";

    for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($select); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
        echo "[",$data[$x]['id'],",",$data[$x]['lat'],",",$data[$x]['lon'],"]";
        if ($x <= (mysqli_num_rows($select)-2) ) {
            echo ",";
        }
    }
        echo "];";

    mysqli_close($konek);
?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you view the browser source, what do you see for the bindPopup line?

Comment: The `bindPopup` method wants a single text string as parameter as far as I can tell, so outputting the result of `json_encode($rows)` there makes very little sense. First of all, you want to output the data for _one_ row there, not all of them at the same time (and multiple times), so that should rather be accessing `$row[$i]` in the first place. But, since you are selecting _two_ columns from your database, you would still have to decide which one to actually output there, resp. combine the content of both into one single string first.

Comment: I just checked on "view page source", in the bindPopup literally it shows the data in database just fine and yet the map wont load on my page

Comment: _“in the bindPopup literally it shows the data in database just fine and yet the map wont load on my page”_ - it can look “fine” to you all day long, but that doesn’t mean much, if this isn’t even the data type the method expects to begin with.

Comment: You still haven’t said which value you actually want to output in the popup. Also unclear what `planelatlong` actually contains. Do the records in there match what you have in $rows from your database, in number and order? Otherwise, you need to explain what the connection between those two is supposed to be in the first place.

Comment: The value in the popup will be "Dep and mag" from database, thats all i wanted to print. The records should be matched.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a geojson file from php and then process it like any other from leaflet.

```
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.control;

        var popupText = feature.properties.description 
            layer.bindPopup(popupText)
            layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.title).openTooltip(); 
            }
            });
```